# How to make the title in the titlebar moveable? | ANDROID

Tags: android, title, titlebar

I have set my title with setTitle() in the class. Now I want to know how to code this in the class when the title is too long to be shown in the titlebar that the title is moveable or moves by itself.

Can somebody help me?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make a `TextView` scrolling automatically:

```
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="a loooong text" 
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
       android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

And you may need to do following in your code as well:

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to code this not in the layout rather in the class?

Comment: Yes, call the corresponding Java methods for each attribute setting you see in above XML.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post in the answer how this works? Then I check your answer!